# How do i export the key for my app android to use with facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

How do i export the key for my app using the debug defaults specified by the Android SDK and Eclipse I am trying to generate a key for use with the Facebook SDK I have tried

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64

if it helps i am running ubuntu 11.04
but what it generates is gibberish if i may say so
thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

If gibberish means random characters and numbers, about 30 of them:
Thats fine and what you need. Just take them and copy them to your applications profile on Facebook.

If not, please post the error or command output you get while doing so.